# Loading .pbmm and .scorer file (Mozilla DeepSpeech)

Tags: python, tensorflow, speech-recognition, mozilla-deepspeech

I'm trying to load .pbmm and .scorer models available in the Mozilla Deepspeech documentation.

The `load_model()` function of Tensorflow doesn't support this file type and throws this error:

```
OSError: Unable to open file (file signature not found).
```

I ultimately wish to get the hidden layer responses of the deepspeech model for a specific research purpose. It would be great if someone could tell me how to load this model or suggest other speech recognition models that could help solve this purpose of getting hidden layer responses. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add a link to those files, docs and small code snipped with what you have tried? Also should add at least the tensorflow version

Comment: This is the code snippet: from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

import tensorflow as tf
model1_file='/content/drive/MyDrive/deepspeech-0.9.3-models.pbmm'
model2_file='/content/drive/MyDrive/deepspeech-0.9.3-models.scorer'
loaded_model1 = tf.keras.models.load_model(model1_file)
loaded_model2= tf.keras.models.load_model(model2_file)

Comment: please, update the question with this data to let others help you

Answer (score 0):

This section of the [DeepSpeech PlayBook](https://mozilla.github.io/deepspeech-playbook/DEPLOYMENT.html) has more information on model deployment, and contains information on how to convert `.pbmm` files to other formats.